# javascript data type for numerical value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var id = id++;
console.log(id);
```

I just wonder why this isn't work? I put it inside a function, I was expecting it start from 2, and then increment 1 by 1. But in the console what I see is NaN. Why?

Comment: var id = id++; (id++? before id is available ?,so id = undefined )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you initialize a variable (=assign some value to it), its value is `undefined` and `undefined++` is not a number (`NaN`).

Answer (score 1):

`id` is `undefined`, `undefined++` is NaN.

You are using a variable which is not defined before, so NaN is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value to `id`.

You need to initialize it.

Try:

```
var id = 1;
id++;
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean?

```
var id = 1;
id++;
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't increment something that isn't already defined. So undefined ++ is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you didn't asign a value to "id" variable, so first you need to declare and initialize a variable, then you can manipulate it's value.

var id; //declare
id = 1; //initialize;
id += 1 or id++  //manipulate it(increment the value with 1);

or shorter:

```
var id = 1;
id++;
```